# cmake Could not find a package configuration file provided by "glfw3"

Tags: c++, cmake, clion, glfw

I am trying to add glfw to my c++ project. I am using cmake and CLion. I am getting the error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:11 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findglfw3.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "glfw3", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "glfw3" (requested
  version 3.3) with any of the following names:

    glfw3Config.cmake
    glfw3-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "glfw3" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "glfw3_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "glfw3"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

I downloaded glfw using homebrew (`brew install glfw`) and put the downloaded contents in my project. My project structure looks like this

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpZjO.png)

my CMakeLists.txt looks like this

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(open_gl)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_executable(open_gl src/Application.cpp)

list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")

# glfw
find_package(glfw3 3.3 REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(open_gl glfw)
```

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong? Might just be making some beginner mistake but I have been at this for way too long now.

Comment: Where does `brew` install its packages? Does it contain any of the files mentioned in the error message? Are they located in a place where CMake will find them?

Comment: Brew installs its packages in /usr/local/Cellar (/glfw). I then moved the installed folder to my project directory. The mentioned file `glfw3Config.cmake` is in my project folder under `/dependencies/glfw/include/lib/cmake/glfw3/glfw3Config.came`. I don't actually know if and how CMake finds it.

Comment: As you can see from the error message, variable `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` affects **only** on searching for `Findglfw3.cmake` script. Since you don't have this script, setting this variable has a little sense. You have the script `glfw3Config.cmake`, which search can be hinted e.g. with `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` variable.